# Singleton vs prototype JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc, singleton, spring-jdbc

Per [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/1.2.x/reference/jdbc.html), a JDBCTemplate class "can be used within a service implementation via direct instantiation with a DataSource reference, or get prepared in an application context and given to services as bean reference."

```
public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

I was wondering, what is the advantage of this solution over define the `jdbctemplate` as singleton in the context and directly inject it in the `Dao`

```
 public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {
        @Autowired
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
        public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: It is little bit late but I also curious. If uses in case1, it will generate JdbcTemplate instances as many as DAOs, right? but in second case, there would be only one JdbcTemplate instance, since spring manages its bean as singleton in default.
In this reason, I think second way looks much better. Is there any way to use JdbcTemplate like case 1?

Comment: @JuneyoungOh JdbcTemplate has some properties that effect all queries executed from the given instance (e.g. `setFetchSize(int fetchSize)`, `setQueryTimeout(int queryTimeout)` etc.) So if you use one of those and need different settings for different parts of the application - you need multiple instances of JdbcTemplate.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It was a helpful answer, I did not think about those cases. Have a good day bb

Comment: What is the correlation between a spring JdbcTemplate and sql-connection, if any ? Does having 4 JdbcTemplate objects mean that we have made 4 connections to the sql server ?

Comment: @elMowgli JdbcTemplate has a dependency on a DataSource - `JdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource)`. Usually the DataSource acts as a connection pool - e.g. when the JdbcTemplate have to execute and SQL statement it gets a Connection from the DataSource(Pool), executes the statement and than returns the connection in the Pool.

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov thanks, clarified bunch of conceptual doubts I was having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the class-level documentation of JdbcTemplate:

> Can be used within a service implementation via direct instantiation
> with a DataSource reference, or get prepared in an application context
> and given to services as bean reference.

Either is OK. Here I have a large application (50 DAOs, 100 concurrent users) and there is one jdbcTemplate object for the entire application, defined in the Spring context. This works fine.

Comment: can someone address the context of the other answer below? does it make sense? thanks, just doing research

Answer (score 2):

One drawback of injecting the `JdbcTemplate` directly is if you need to/decide to use a `SQLExceptionTranslator`.

If your `JdbcTemplate` is a singleton, setting a `SQLExceptionTranslator` in any class affects all classes using that template.

For example...

```
public class JbdcUserDAO implements UserDAO{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JbdcUserDAO() {
        this.jdbcTemplate.setExceptionTranslator(new UserSQLExceptionTranslator());
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

AND

```
public class JdbcCompanyDAO implements CompanyDAO{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcCompanyDAO() {

    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

`SQLException`s raised through `JdbcCompanyDAO` will also be run through `UserSQLExceptionTranslator` even though it looks like no translator is registered.